# What is the word for someone who doesn’t follow the laws and governmental powers of their country

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, expressions, vocabulary

I’m currently trying to find the word one would describe a person that does not follow the governmental structure and laws of their country.

My example is the views some native maori people of NZ have towards the crown, they do not conform to the crowns forced power as it is not British land but that of the traditional owners.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Have you tried searching for previously asked questions? I feel this has been asked before. Please use the more apt "single-word-requests" tag and abide by its [usage guidelines](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: That would be an *Elected Representative* of the country.

Comment: The term will depend on the motivations for the disobedience and on what the person using the term thinks about these motivations. The 'example' used in the body of the question is far too specific to be an example of the broad question formulated in the title. It presents in an overly simple way a matter that involves some complex issues of the history, laws, and political system of New Zealand, and of Maori culture and social organisation, which may all have impact on what terms one would use when speaking about it. Discussing all that properly would be well outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 0):

***recusant:*** one who refuses to accept or obey established authority [(Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/recusant)
                      a person who refuses to submit to an authority or to comply with a regulation. [(Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/recusant)

Also an adjective ('Of or denoting a recusant').

> *The Lancashire desolation and remoteness was a refuge for **recusants** - awkward people who were stubborn and resilient, and whose best expression was not in word but in action and a capacity to come back for more persecution.*
>
> <sup>(example in Lexico)</sup>
>
> *Some refused compliance with the tariff. The **recusants** were adjudged to be in the wrong.*
>
> <sup>(example in the OED)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

(Adjective)
REBELLIOUS = showing a desire to resist authority, control and want to break rules.
Ex. Some students become very rebellious and haven't follows the school rules

Comment: Hello, Vineet. If you check at the suggested duplicate, you will find that this (along with many other) answers has already been given. 'Rebel' as an actual answer and 'rebellious' in one.